# Объединить многоуровневый массив по одинаковому элементу

Tags: javascript

Ести массив `[["qwe","Ivanov",10],["qwe","Petrov",10],["rty","Ivanov",1],["rty","Sidorov",30]]`
Нужно получить `[[["qwe"],[["Ivanov",10],["Petrov",10]]],[["rty"],[["Ivanov",1],["Sidorov",30]]]]`
Объединяем подмассивы по одинаковому первому элементу
Помогите, пожалуйста, преобразовать массив подобным способом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. берем первый элемент исходного массива
2. фильтруем элементы массива через `filter()`, оставляем те, в которых есть найденный ранее элемент, складываем в отдельный массив
3. все эти же элементы удаляем из исходного массива через `filter()`
4. складываем в результирующий массив элемент и те массивы, в которые он входил
5. повторяем до тех пор пока исходный массив не станет пустым

Пример:

```
let mass = [["qwe","Ivanov",10],["qwe","Petrov",10],["rty","Ivanov",1],["rty","Sidorov",30]];
let resMass = [];
while(mass.length > 0) {
    let first = mass[0][0];
    let arrFiltered = mass.filter(elem => elem[0] === first);
    for (let key in arrFiltered) {
        arrFiltered[key] = arrFiltered[key].filter((elem, index) => index !== 0);
    }
    mass = mass.filter(elem => elem[0] !== first);
    resMass.push([first, arrFiltered]);
}
console.log(resMass);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!  Работает отлично. Не думал,  что будет так много фильтров!  Есть чему научиться!